# Use of unresolved identifier 'cell' when populating UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I'm new to Swift and following a tutorial series. The tutorial seems to jump around and not follow a step by step format which is leading to several errors in my code. I have managed to debug most of these, but this one will not go away.

I do not understand why 'cell' is not recognised even though it is defined above. This may be a really simple question, or something specific to the new Xcode update (running Xcode 9.2).

I am trying to populate a UITableViewCell with a user image in code.

Any help would be much appreciated

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    if indexPath.row == 0 {
        if let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "ShareSomethingCell") as? ShareSomethingCell {
            cell.configCell(userImageUrl: currentUserImageUrl)
            cell.shareBtn.addTarget(self, action: #selector(toCreatePost(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
        }
        return cell
    }
    return UITableViewCell()
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I do not understand why 'cell' is not recognised even though it is defined above

Because:

- Curly braces constitute a *scope*; what's declared inside a scope, stays inside that scope.
- `if let` (conditional binding) works in a special way: it declares the `let` variable *inside* the curly braces *after* the condition.

So, put that together and you get this:

```
    if let cell = ... {
        // `cell` is defined HERE...
    }
    // `cell` is NOT defined here...
    return cell // error
```

Answer (score 0):

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "ShareSomethingCell") as? ShareSomethingCell 
    if indexPath.row == 0 {
        cell.configCell(userImageUrl: currentUserImageUrl)
        cell.shareBtn.addTarget(self, action: #selector(toCreatePost(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
    }
    return cell
}
```